# Exact onselected event in radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, radio-button, onchange

All,

I have 2 radio buttons in my form. By default no button will be selected. When the user clicks any radio button, corresponding text boxes will be enabled [ tried onclick, onchange for this ].
Above functionality is working fine.
But, Im facing a little tricky problem here. When the user browses back, though one radio button is selected no corresponding text boxes were displaying until clicking the selected radio button again..

Is there any radio button event to capture this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you might be having issue due to caching...? Btw can you show some relevant code...?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$(function(){
$('input[name=radiobuttonname]').removeAttr('checked');
})
```

On document ready it will make both button unchecked.

Hope this helps...